# File Size Increased in Server (HDFS) when uploaded from jmeter

Tags: upload, jmeter, hdfs

I am trying to upload file in HDFS (server) from jmeter. As I see, file is uploaded in HDFS successfully but the file size is slightly increased. Thus, making file corrupt. And file doesn't work as expected.

The same file I uploaded using Postman and it works fine. There is no change in file size in HDFS and the file works as expected.

here is the requested body in jmeter which shows success message and file is in server

```
 POST http://myurl/../..

POST data:
--HTKJ_hgyyM7QVWQfJBS5X-WQX0zkMO5fqmlY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1.pak"; filename="file1.pak" 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--HTKJ_hgyyM7QVWQfJBS5X-WQX0zkMO5fqmlY--


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
file_name: jmeter13.pak
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 11563
Host: 10.45.3.64:8080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_111)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of your POST request, Jmeter is wrapping the following headers within the boundary to the actual file content before sending to the server.

> POST data:
>   --HTKJ_hgyyM7QVWQfJBS5X-WQX0zkMO5fqmlY
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1.pak"; filename="file1.pak" 
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   
>   --HTKJ_hgyyM7QVWQfJBS5X-WQX0zkMO5fqmlY--

In case you want to send the actual file within the body, try removing the “Parameter Name” in the “Files Upload” box of the HTTP request as stated in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

`File Path:
Name of the file to send. If left blank, JMeter does not send a file, if filled in, JMeter automatically sends the request as a multipart form request.
If it is a POST or PUT or PATCH request and there is a single file whose 'Parameter name' attribute (below) is omitted, then the file is sent as the entire body of the request, i.e. no wrappers are added. This allows arbitrary bodies to be sent. This functionality is present for POST requests, and also for PUT requests.See below for some further information on parameter handling.`

This worked for me, please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is Postman and JMeter being configured differently. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and carefully inspect JMeter request paying attention to literally everything, especially to the "Request Headers"as they matter. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for comprehensive information on JMeter tests troubleshooting.

If you won't be able to figure out the differences using View Results Tree listener you can capture requests from JMeter and Postman using a "lower level" network sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)  which is the most advanced network traffic analyzer, you will be able to detect a single byte inconsistency with it.

If above tips won't help please update your question with Postman and JMeter configurations and maybe Wireshark `.pcap` trace for both the requests so I or other community members  could take a look and suggest the appropriate changes.

Comment: I added view result tree and didn't found any error in. (file uploaded successfully). I don't know how to use wireshark. The file uploaded successfully from both jmeter and postman but there is a slight different in file size when uploaded form jmeter

Comment: Hello, Dmitri T, here is the link [jmeter_uploadfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h85hv6lqtoho05r/jmeter_fileupload.pcap?dl=0)
 to the .pcap file. Please view it and let me know. 
[jmeter_uploadfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h85hv6lqtoho05r/jmeter_fileupload.pcap?dl=0)
Thank you.